# How to apply Composite-Iterator

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I'm trying to figure out how can i merge iterator and composite objects.
what can be the best implementation for a struct below.

```
class Composite<Item> : Item
{

}

class Iterator<Item>
{

}

class Iterable<Item>
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, it's rare that you would do iterators in this method.  Typically, you'd just use your item within a generic collection.

As for the [Composite Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) - the main motivation behind this pattern is to allow your composite to be treated as if it's just an item.  This typically means you can "combine" a composite with iteration merely by doing:

```
// Given:
public class Composite<Item> : IItem {}
```

You can do:

```
List<IItem> items = new List<IItem>();
items.Add(new Item());
items.Add(new Composite<Item>());
items.Add(new Item());

// Iterate through the items...
foreach(var item in items)
{
    item.Foo();
}
```